# Adding a UserCreationForm to html in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a registration page for my website.  I have a bootstrap/html template with a form (Down Bellow), and I want to replace the html form with a `UserCreationForm` that I have already made in my forms.py file. The tutorial says to replace the html input fields with my user creation fields, but then bootstrap cannot style them.
**Forms.py:**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]
```

**Form parameters: (These are the fields from the UserCreationForm that I want to replace the HTML form fields with).**

```
<form method = "POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %} 

    {{form.username.label}}
    {{form.username}}

    {{form.email.label}}
    {{form.email}}

    {{form.first_name.label}}
    {{form.first_name}}

    {{form.last_name.label}}
    {{form.last_name}}

    {{form.password1.label}}
    {{form.password1}}

    {{form.password2.label}}
    {{form.password2}}
    <input type="submit" name="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: What about styling them on the basis of a CSS selector?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to look toward the following approach, if you can and willing to modify your `UserCreationForm` a bit:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    # other fields as needed...
    username = forms.CharField(
                    max_legth=100,
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'FOO_CLASS'}))
# Added a class to our input fields
```

So, now you can hook onto the specified class `.form-control`. In your CSS file and in HTML file in the question, this class supposedly introduces the styles.

Then (after your `forms.py` is modified) the template should look like this:

```
<div class="signup-form">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account!</p>
        <hr>
        <form method = "POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="form-group">    
            {{form.username.label}}
            {{form.username}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{form.email.label}}
            {{form.email}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{form.first_name.label}}
            {{form.first_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{form.last_name.label}}
            {{form.last_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{form.password1.label}}
            {{form.password1}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{form.password2.label}}
            {{form.password2}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="hint-text">Already have an account? <a href="#">Login here</a></div>
</div>
```

There are some other ideas based on using the `~` CSS selector and targeting the `labels` or `input`s themselves. But this one is based on the Django's framework facilities.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do that! If you want to, please upvote my question so it can help the community.

Comment: @boetis you're welcome! Please test this out and cue me in, if it won't go the desired way.

Comment: How would I put the username field in my HTML? Standard {} does not seem to work.

Comment: @boetis now I don't see why you can't include the fields with the `{{ form.username }}` and then hook up the bootstrap's classes on them. Can you explain what's the problem with this approach?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to do that, I'm not getting an error or anything my form field is just not styling.

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: @boetis then you just want to replace the HTML's form inputs with your `form.username` and others, then to include the desired bootstrap styles in your `forms.py` as in my post.

Comment: @boetis I may try to do illustration on the whole thing if it helps, but later. For now, I would encourage you to consider the mentioned method and try it out on your setup.

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do. I am going to update my question with my CSS so you can see what I am talking about. I want to replace the current HTML form fields with my forms.py ones.

Comment: can you please quickly look at my CSS?

Comment: can you please quicky look at my CSS?

Comment: @boetis already did, check the edit to the post. You basically need to add your `.form-control` class to the `Widget` to your fields in your `forms.py` (I assume you have separate file for form classes named `forms.py`), as I did in the answer.

Comment: still doesn't work, thank you for all of the help though, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @boetis you may check the latest edit. Does it change anything in the styles? Did you added to the `Widget`'s `attrs` the `.form-control` class?

Comment: thank you for all of your help! I got it working, but it is displaying the fields a little weird. Let me update my question with a screenshot as to how I want it to look vs how it looks. I have been debugging and trying to fix this but have not found any luck. - On a side note, I really appreciate you going out of your way to help me. I am new to Django and I don't know all of its features yet.

Comment: I added images to my question to show you my problem.

Comment: @boetis all good, friend! I assume the main trouble is in the fact that your form has `label`s while the inputs in pure html mostly doesn't (it uses `placeholder` attribute to "label" the fields such as "*Username*" and so on). You may want to delete the `{{form.username.label}}` (and other labels), and then to check what you're getting. Since then the extraneous *boxes* will go away, I would wait for the layout to become more clean. Afterwards, if there still will be some trouble, I would consider introducing custom CSS rules. Not the best approach, but a solution for sure.

Comment: I finally got it working! Thank you for all of your help! I ended up using crispy forms to style my inputs. Quick question, I did what you told me to do in my forms.py file, but I am unable to change the max_lenght or any attribute of my username field, I don't know what is happening, can you please help?

Comment: it say's something about my views.py file. I have updated my question to include my views file.

Comment: @boetis hey friend, I'm glad to help but I can't walk through with you on the whole project, as well as continually adding in new subquestions is not a way to go here. I would say that the initial question has its answer. As to new ones, the `views.py` is in the basics of Django framework, you should look into it yourself if it doesn't make sense for you yet. As to the `max_lenght`, you can modify it in your `forms.py`, on each field as you want. Please consider accepting this answer and then to post another question if you'll meet any trouble further down the road.

Comment: @boetis best of luck!